# Upload to nextcloud via webDAV using one single meta-user

Tags: upload, credentials, webdav, nextcloud

is there a way to upload to users folders without having their individual credentials?
By using a meta-user? I want do drop files for other users. How can I do so?

Thanks in advance
Nicolas Heyne

I tried to use webdav with an admin user and there was a message stating there's no access to the desired folder.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution:

1. create user
2. create user folder in folders of admin user
3. share folder with created user
4. share files by uploading to admin users shared folder